# Listing directories with tab as delimiter

Tags: linux, bash, unix, zsh, ls

When we list files in unix using `ls -l` command the output is a table with space as a separator, for example the following

```
(jupyter-lab) ➜  mylab ls -l
total 2
drwxr-sr-x. 2 hs0424 ragr  0 Feb  1 12:17 A bad directory
drwxr-sr-x. 2 hs0424 ragr  0 Feb  1 12:18 A very bad directory
```

I want to convert to a tab separated file (`.tsv`), just changing spaces to `\t`, such as `ls -l | sed -E 's/ +/\t/g'` would not work since filenames contain spaces. Do we have better solution ?

Hard to show expected output with tabs but if we use `\t` as a replacement of tab, I want something as follows,

```
(jupyter-lab) ➜  mylab ls -l
total 2
drwxr-sr-x.\t2\ths0424\tragr\t0\tFeb 1\t12:17\tA bad directory
drwxr-sr-x.\t2\ths0424\tragr\t0\tFeb 1\t12:18\tA very bad directory
```

(Edit 1)
We can assume access to GNU tools

Comment: Why are you using `ls` at all?

Comment: And, just as importantly, which OS/distro are you targeting? Can we assume GNU tools?

Comment: please update the question to show the expected output; also of interest may be an explanation of the benefit (?) of replacing spaces with tabs

Comment: ("expected output" is important: not all operating systems' versions of `ls` behave the same way! The POSIX standard specifies _some_ of its output, but it's not by any means exhaustive, which is part of why [parsing `ls` programatically is innately unreliable](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)).

Comment: just added expected output

Comment: @CharlesDuffy please suggest alternatives, would love to know more.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy just saw your answer, testing it now.

Comment: Alternatives depend on the "why". I've added an answer, and a link above that's hopefully informative; also, see [BashFAQ #87](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/087).

Comment: Note, by the way, that filenames can legally contain literal newlines; so it's safer to have them in NUL-delimited form than newline-delimited form.

Comment: I don't think that there is really useful way to do it. You could of course use `tr` to translate every space into a tab, but this means that spaces inside the filename also become a tab. Perhaps it makes more sense to write your custom `ls` for this. You can loop over all files and use the `stat` command to collect the information on the file you need to go into your table.

Comment: Why is this tagged bash **and* zsh?

Comment: @user1934428 I thought there could be shell-specific functionalities. For solution without `ls` please check the answer.

Comment: @HirakSarkar : Even in this case, you need to specify then the shell you are interested in. Consider the case that you get two answers, one for bash and one for zsh. Which one would you accept (since SO allows you to accept only one answer)? If you need solutions for two shells, ask two separate questions.

Comment: @user1934428 fair point. Often zsh-based users are also knowledgable in bash so I was casting a wider net. I think the answer given works in both shells though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use GNU `find -printf` or `stat`, either of which let you provide an arbitrary format string, instead of `ls`.

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf '%M\t%y\t%g\t%G\t%u\t%U\t%f\t%l\n'
```

or

```
# for normal cases
stat --printf='%A\t%G\t%g\t%U\t%u\t%n\n' *

# for directories where filenames could exceed command line length limit
printf '%s\0' * | xargs -0 stat --printf='%A\t%G\t%g\t%U\t%u\t%n\n'
```